# in-app purchasing sandbox tests work on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app which uses inApp purchasing. The code is all setup and I've setup my in-app purchase in iTunesConnect. When I test the inApp functionality on my iPhone 5 iOS7 hooked up to Xcode everything works as predicted. it cycles trough the products (in this case only one) and identifies whether or not it has been purchased, it also allows me to purchase it with my sandbox account. when I test it on an iPhone 4 iOS7 it also works, and when i test it on an iPhone 4 iOS6 it also works. However when I try to test it on my friends iPad mini running iOS6 it always reports back as 0 products found??? I am concerned that if I release the app like this it might bug out in for the end users.

I've tried rebooting Xcode, my mac & the iPad and still the same result.

Is there something i need to setup in Organizer to allow this device to use in-app purchasing in sandbox mode?

Is there any iPad specific code that i am missing for in-app purchasing?

My friends iPad is Jailbroken could this have anything to do with this?

Comment: No API is exactly the same - are you sure both detects sandbox mode properly ? Sometimes it's just apple problem - just try again tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out on my own after hours of googling. hopefully this will help someone else. So that fact that my friends iPad was jailbroken was this issue. you can test on a jailbroken device but you just need to remove Appsync from the device and then it will work as you expect.